How do I send a google.protobuf.Value object using protobuf-net.Grpc and code-first?
The protobuf format has the type google.protobuf.Value described in Create Protobuf messages for .NET apps.
There is also a Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value type in the Google.Protobuf, Version=3.28.0.0 library.
I can send google.protobuf.Value with a message described by such a proto-file:
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Status);
}

message Status {
    google.protobuf.Value data = 3;
}

As a result, I will get a generated dot with a "data" field of the type Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value. I can assign an arbitrary JsonDocument to this "data" in the following way and everything will be transmitted perfectly.
var dto = new Status();
dto.Data = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value.Parser.ParseJson(myJsonDocument.RootElement.ToString())

I used protobuf-net.Grpc and applied code-first by creating such a dto with the field Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value
[DataContract]
public class ObjectTypeDto
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value Data { get; set; }
}

If I pass my myJsonDocument through it as before, I get an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value
I used the tool https://protogen.marcgravell.com and generated the following dto from the above proto file:
// <auto-generated>
//   This file was generated by a tool; you should avoid making direct changes.
//   Consider using 'partial classes' to extend these types
//   Input: my.proto
// </auto-generated>
#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable CS0612, CS0618, CS1591, CS3021, IDE0079, IDE1006, RCS1036, RCS1057, RCS1085, RCS1192
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract()]
public partial class Status : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension                 
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref     
    __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, Name = @"data")]
    public global::Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value Data { get; set; }

}

[global::System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract(Name = @"Greeter")]
public partial interface IGreeter
{
    global::System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Status>     
SayHelloAsync(global::ProtoBuf.Grpc.CallContext context = default);
}
#pragma warning restore CS0612, CS0618, CS1591, CS3021, IDE0079, IDE1006, RCS1036, RCS1057, RCS1085, RCS1192
#endregion

When I try to return the result from the method in this dto, I get the same exception.
How do I send a google.protobuf.Value(Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value) object using protobuf-net.Grpc and code-first?
